# separate each sendmail with its own maillog?

Tags: sendmail

I have 2 sendmail on my server ( instance sendmail ), I want to separate each sendmail with its own maillog?

sendmail version  sendmail-8.13.8-8

and how i can see each mail queue for each instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume that your two instances run with different configuration files. You can view the queues by running `mailq -C config_file.cf`.

You have to make sure that your separate instances use different queue directories (you can specify this in the configuration file).

To separate logging, one trick is to use the -L command line option for sendmail and differentiate using its argument.